# URL encoding difference between Mozilla and Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mozilla, url-encoding

I have the following url
[image]

It contains a parameter `?key=vE$%fds9` which I am reading into my JavaScript program.

Per url encoding cross reference at https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp the  `%fd` translates to a `ý` character.

It is behaving differently between Mozilla and Chrome browsers.

Chrome returns a `ý` result as expected
[image]
Mozilla returns a `�`
[image]
Anybody know how I can modify the JavaScript so that Mozilla translates it properly?

As always, thanks to the experts out there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use the utf-8 encoding for this character which is [`%C3%BD`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

so this should be `?key=vE$%C3%BDs9` to be compatible in all browser versions

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Thank you @MohammedEssehemy